# Как получить последнюю часть из url?

Tags: php

```
http://site.com/filter/page
```

Как разобрать url и получить `page` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для более общего вида URL:

```
$url = "http://example.com/some/path/?param=value#hash";
$path= parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

$result = array_pop(explode("/", trim($path, "/")));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: я бы сделал end. мало ли, массив еще где-то пригодится

Answer (score 4):

Используйте две функции (на случай, если у вас еще и параметры в url могут быть):

1. [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) со вторым параметром **PHP_URL_PATH** для выделения пути `/filter/page`;
2. [explode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) для разбиения строки `/filter/page` в массив по разделителю **/**.

Из массива вам следует взять **последний элемент**.

P.S. Если параметров в url не предвидится, то можно обойтись только `explode()`.

P.P.S. Перед `explode()` можно выполнить `trim($str, '/')` для удаления финишнего слеша.

Comment: прям описание кода в моем ответе :D

Comment: @teran, :P :b :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$url='http://site.com/filter/page';
$last_arr=explode('/', $url);
echo $last_arr[count($last_arr)-1];
```